# Core dumps while starting daemon for cpp program

Tags: c++, linux, bash, centos, start-stop-daemon

My question is about a daemon for a program which I created in c++ language. The program uses some threads and while I try to start the daemon it says ***Starting program: bash: line 1: 21021 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) /path/to/program***. OS is Centos 6. *I read many posts about oversizing the core size in order to make core size capable to handle multiple threads,but the same error...* Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: gdb is your friend